# Exception for Unhandle observer

Tags: ios

I am using following code to add observer:

```
[self.priorityQueue addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"operations" options:options context:NULL];
```

And observe method is defined as:

```
-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                     change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSOperationQueue class]] && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"operations"]) {
        //calling my method
    }
    else {       
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object
                      change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

but I am getting following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: ' (
>    Context: 0x0, Property: 0x110bf60> ): An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
>   Key path: operations
>   Observed object: {name = 'NSOperationQueue 0x11213c0'}
>   Change:

Please tell me, if I am doing some mistake in my observer method.

Thanks,

Comment: All this code you pasted it's inside one class? Are you extending NSObject or what ?

Comment: Yes .. all this code is in same class  and I am extending NSObject class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSObject is not implementing that function - if you are extending NSObject never call super.

From Apple docs:

```
 Be sure to call the superclass's implementation *if it implements it*.
 NSObject does not implement the method.
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html